# adding point on y-axis HIGHCHARTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to render a bar chart.
    I have created a horizontal line from a point on y-axis which shows the average of the data using `addPlotLine()`.

What I want is how to insert a corresponding label on y-axis for this line.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Having the same problem here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018948/add-a-specific-y-axis-label-with-highcharts/32019174#32019174

Answer (score 0):

Each plotLine have built-in lables, see the option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.label

Comment: I used that as well but it does not mark a point on the y-axis.

Comment: So label should be displayed on axis, not next to line?

Comment: Yes, just like all y-axis labels.

Comment: Please attach mockup.